# The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST is not working

Tags: php, laravel

I want to delete bookings this is my form

```
 <form action="{{ route('bookings.delete', $booking->id) }}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        @method('delete')
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
   </form>
```

this is my controller

```
public function delete($id){
    $booking = Booking::find($id);
    $booking->delete();
}
```

and this is my route

```
Route::post('/bookings/delete', 'BookingController@delete')->name('bookings/delete');
```

Comment: `bookings/delete != bookings.delete` and the route you are showing is a POST route not a DELETE route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route should be defined as

```
Route::delete('/bookings/delete/{id}', 'BookingController@delete')->name('bookings.delete');
```

**You should also pass the id as a route parameter**

In the delete method of your controller

```
public function delete($id) 
{
         $booking = Booking::findOrFail($id);
         $booking->delete();

         return redirect()->route('bookings.index');
}
```

Comment: I added the id then it is redirecting to page not found

Comment: Once I click delete it is redirecting to http://localhost:8000/bookings/delete?44. Instead of the page bookings pages.

Answer (score 2):

In your route file

```
name('bookings/delete');
```

Should be

```
name('bookings.delete');
```

Try it and let us know

Answer (score 0):

if you need to use `@method('delete')` then your route should be `delete()` not `post`

```
Route::delete('/bookings/delete/{id}', 'BookingController@delete')->name('bookings.delete');
```

And form:

```
<form action="{{ route('bookings.delete', $booking->id) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('delete')
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Once I clicked delete it is redirecting to http://localhost:8000/bookings/delete?44. Which does not exist